# Laravel live ajax search - token mismatch

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am making a live search where user can search for business.

This would be done using ajax and display results however I get an error that there is an TokenMismatchException.

Here's my code:

Ajax:

```
function search_data(search_value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/searching/' + search_value,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')
    }
    }).done(function(response){
        $('#results').html(response);          // put the returning html in the 'results' div
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public function search($search) {
    $search_text = $search;
    if ($search_text==NULL) {
        $data= Business::all();
    } else {
        $data=Business::where('name','LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')->get();
    }
    return view('results')->with('results',$data);
}
}
```

Route::

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('tfgm', 'GuzzleController@tfgm')->name('tfgm');;
    Route::get('odeon', 'GuzzleController@odeon')->name('odeon');;
    Route::get('chronicle', 'GuzzleController@oldham_chronicle')->name('chronicle');;
    Route::get('smokeyard', 'GuzzleController@smokeyard')->name('smokeyard');;
    Route::get('profile/', 'ProfileController@checkid')->name('profile');;
    Route::get('create/business', 'BusinessController@addBusiness')->name('createBusiness');
    Route::get('business/list', 'BusinessController@viewBusiness')->name('viewBusiness');
    Route::get('business/{id}', 'BusinessController@displayBusiness')->name('displayBusiness');

    Route::post('/searching/{search}', 'SearchController@search');
    Route::post('update', 'ProfileController@updateProfile');   
    Route::post('create', 'BusinessController@createBusiness');    
    Route::post('image', 'ImageController@image');
    Route::post('test2', 'ImageController@gallery');
    Route::post('markers', 'BusinessController@saveMarkers');
    Route::post('reviews', 'BusinessController@saveReviews');
});
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/redirect/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@callback');
```

master.blade.php

```
<head>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</head>
                        <form action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_text" onkeyup="search_data(this.value, 'result');" placeholder="Search">
                            </div>
                                <div id="result">
                                    @include('results')
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Are you applying the correct middleware to the route? VerifyCsrfToken, EncryptCookies, etc.?

Comment: I guess I do, you can confirm this by looking at my edited post

Comment: `'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')` Your name does not match with meta tag. You have written `csrf-token` in meta tag.

Comment: Good catch, should be X-CSRF-TOKEN

Comment: changed it to : 'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') still same error

Comment: Thats still incorrect, it should be X-CSRF-TOKEN: $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')

Comment: X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') it should be like this I guess it's working as I don't get any errors

Comment: @Przemek 
     `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line must be

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax code you have written `X-CSRFToken` that is wrong. Correct is `X-CSRF-TOKEN`

Always use below code in you script file

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change X-CSRFToken to X-CSRF-TOKEN